# how to simplify an array of arrays with single object attribute

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, object, data-manipulation

I have the following data structure:

```
$campaigns =
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [subject] => cca-cpg
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [subject] => cleanup-cpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [subject] => gas-cpg
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [subject] => pollinators-cpg
    )

)
```

what I would like to end up with is:

```
$campaigns = ['cca-cpg','clean_up-cpg','gas-cpg','pollinators-cpg'];


this will work:
$newCampaigns=[];
for($i=0;$i<count($campaigns);$i++){
   array_push($newCampaigns,$campaigns[$i]['subject'];
}
```

but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.  The data is coming directly from a mysql database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `array_column()` function for you:

```php
$newCampaigns = array_column($campaigns, 'subject');
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php